# iPhone 5 app fails to install through iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes

I have an iPhone app which was designed to run on the older iPhone screen size. It installs perfectly on iPhone 4 as well as iPhone 5 through iTunes on Windows. However, when I added extra nibs to the app to support the iPhone 5 extended screen, the new app doesn't get installed on either of the devices even with the same code signing identity. Could anyone cast some light on this about what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Is this for an app that you released through the store, or one that are deploying in an enterprise environment?

Comment: It's not an app that I need to release to the store. I am trying to send it using a normal distribution profile to a testing team. It is not an Enterprise Distribution Profile. It is just a normal distribution profile where you manually need to add individual UDIDs of target devices.

Comment: Is iTunes giving any error messages. Also does the app install to a device when tethered using Xcode? Additionally have you checked the iOS deployment target (make sure you havent changed this to a version higher than is on your testers devices as this will cause the app to not install)

Comment: We do not have any devices to test here at the development end. And, the deployment target and other build settings are exactly the same. iTunes throws an error message saying "The app "<app_name>" was not installed on the iPhone "<Device_name>" because an unknown error occurred (0xE8008001)"

Comment: I would highly recommend getting at least one device to be able to test on during development as the simulator cannot replicate everything that the device can and also the simulator does not have the same memory limitations as the actual devices. Having a device will make debugging issue much quicker and easier. Might be worth deleting the old app from the devices (if you haven't already) before trying to install again. Also check the the provisioning profiles on the devices are still valid and have not been deleted as they only last for a short period of time.